# How do I pass to link_to_remote a dynamic url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using link_to_remote and want to pass the following:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Skip Remote",
          :url => url ,
          :update => "update-area-#{contact.id}-#{next_todo.id}" %>
```

Where an example of url would be:

```
skip_contact_email_url(contact, email)
```

where contact is an object for model Contact and Email is an object for model Email.

But sometimes the url is skip_contact_letter_url, skip_contact_call_url, etcetera

Here's how I tried to do it, but it isn't working:

```
<% next_todo = contact.next_todo %>
<% url = "skip_contact_#{next_todo.class.name.tableize.singularize}_url" %>
<% url = url + "(#{contact}, #{next_todo})" %>
```

It correctly does the first part of the url (e.g. skip_contact_email_url) but does not pass the object.  It actually looks like an object in the url.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need evaluate your method generation.

```
<% next_todo = contact.next_todo %>
<% url = "skip_contact_#{next_todo.class.name.tableize.singularize}_url" %>
<% url = send(url, contact, next_todo) %>
```

Comment: ah, that's it I was trying url.send(contact, next_todo) but this might be the right way, thanks!

Comment: yes it's not the bad way because url is a string. You need call this method of this string.